# Conditional Formatting referencing another sheet not working in macro enabled worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I've got two sheets within my workbook. One has a table of check boxes (30+). The other has a table of cells linked to those checkboxes. Ideally if the checkbox is ticked, the cell it is in turns blue.

Checkbox Cell on Sheet 1
[image]

Corresponding Cell on Sheet 2
[image]

I'm using excel 2013, but simply using the formula =Sheet2!A1="TRUE" throws up an error that referencing other sheets is not allowed. I have several macros within the sheet and it's saved as .xlsm.

I've also tried adding in a helper column which pulls the "true/false" value from the other sheet. Again this does not work.

[image]

Format painter is again no, as is paste special :(

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: An example workbook with one or two examples of your checkboxes, etc. would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I shall get putting one of those together. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must not check for the string "TRUE" but for TRUE as kind of a value.

This formula will work: `=Sheet2!A1=TRUE`